# Think Python: Chapter 12 Exercise 6

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, iteration

So I'm trying to solve this exercise from think python:

Exercise 6  From Chapter 12:

> What is the longest English word, that remains a valid English word,
>   as you remove its letters one at a time?
>
> Now, letters can be removed from either end, or the middle, but you
>   can’t rearrange any of the letters. Every time you drop a letter, you
>   wind up with another English word. If you do that, you’re eventually
>   going to wind up with one letter and that too is going to be an
>   English word—one that’s found in the dictionary. I want to know what’s
>   the longest word and how many letters does it have?
>
> I’m going to give you a little modest example: Sprite. Ok? You start
>   off with sprite, you take a letter off, one from the interior of the
>   word, take the r away, and we’re left with the word spite, then we
>   take the e off the end, we’re left with spit, we take the s off, we’re
>   left with pit, it, and I.
>
> Write a program to find all words that can be reduced in this way, and
>   then find the longest one.

I started writing some functions but I'm stuck at the check_dict function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def word_list(textfile='words.txt'):
    res = {}
    for word in open(textfile):
        word = word.strip()
        res[word] = word
    return res

def children(s, wl):
    i = 0
    children = []
    while i < len(s):
        temp = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
        if temp in wl:
            children.append(temp)
        i += 1
    return children

def check_dict(s, wl, res = [], called = 0):
    if len(s) == 1 and s in wl:
        res.append(s)
        return res
    else:
        for child in children(s, wl):
            #print(res,'call number ', str(called), 'with s = ', s, 'whose children are: ', children(s, wl))
            res.append(child)
            check_dict(child, wl, res, called+1)

wl = word_list()
print(check_dict('at', wl))
```

The problem I have is that it returns None instead of returning the contents of res unless I run the function with the base case which is s = 'a' or s = 'i'. I know this function runs through every possible path and as such it should return a couple of different res's but I don't quite understand how could I get this function to print only one res that goes all the way from the parameter with which the function is called to the 1 letter long s that adequates to the base case condition.

I know there is a solution on the book but I want to know what I'm doing wrong and how could I fix my version.

Comment: There's no `return` in the `else` branch.

Comment: @Rawing It is a recursive function

Comment: @BhargavRao: It still doesn't return anything (aka None), even if it's recursive.

Comment: In your own words: 1. What is the `res` parameter to `check_dict` supposed to contain, and what is its purpose? 2. What possible values is `check_dict` supposed to be able to return, and what do they indicate?

Comment: 1. res is the resulting trail of words from the complete word to the 1 char string final string. 2. check dict is supposed to be able to return res or False in the case of failure. I wish check dict returned only ['sprite', 'spite', 'spit', 'pit', 'it', 'i']

Comment: @Rawing it is supposed to return None if the base case is not reached i.e.: with a word that don't fulfill all of the conditions of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

1 You need to change word_list function, Your word_list functions gives dict which have only one item where key and value are same i.e. file content. Change function to get list of word from input.txt file

2 In check_dict function, write return function outside of the if-else loop because children(s, wl) function return empty list.

```
def word_list(textfile='input.txt'):
    return open(textfile).read().strip().split(" ")

def children(s, wl):
    i = 0
    children = []
    s_len = len(s)
    while i < len(s):
        temp = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
        if temp in wl:
            children.append(temp)
        i += 1
    return children

def check_dict(s, wl, res = [], called = 0):
    if len(s) == 1 and s in wl:
        res.append(s)
    else:
        for child in children(s, wl):
        #print(res,'call number ', str(called), 'with s = ', s, 'whose children are: ', children(s, wl))
            res.append(child)
            check_dict(child, wl, res, called+1)

    return res

wl = word_list()
a = check_dict('sprite', wl)
```

Comment: 1. that is intended. It is because in python dictionaries are faster to access than lists as they're accessed with a hash function whilst lists need to be traversed.
2. that doesn't work quite well as it will always return True. I've been able to get the output I'm looking for. I will post my solution asap but it just consists of adding a return before the recursive call to check_dict like this: `return check_dict(child, wl, res, called+1)`. I'm not posting it because as of right now I don't understand why it works but my version doesn't.

Comment: yes, dictionaries are faster to access. waiting for your post.